# 404 static error pages in Rails, path context to public resources changes depending on request URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, http-status-code-404, static-pages

I was working on overriding boiler plate 404 Rails page in RAIlS_ROOT/public. This is Rails 3.1.1 hosted on Pasenger.  I noticed that paths in the html document loose context on routes inside a controller resource path in a production environment.  This is probably something basic, but wanted to put it out there.

I have

> /public      /public/404.html
>   /public/error_stylesheet/styles.css
>   /public/error_images/image.jpg

404.html has references to the resources

```
<link href="error_stylesheets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<img src="error_images/errorpageheader.jpg">
```

For example, 
If I request http://app/wrongurlname 
My 404.html loads with resources err_stylesheets and err_images folders are seen and retrieved.

If I request
   http://app/controller/wrong or
   //app/wrong/wrong
The 404 page loads, but can't see the resources.

I was probably not interested in overriding behavior of ApplicationController or routing which seems like it would be necessary to serve erb pages. I'm not sure if serving

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should try this kind of paths:

```
<link href="/error_stylesheets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<img src="/error_images/errorpageheader.jpg">
```

Without first slash you have `relative` paths, but with slash you've got an `absolute` path you need.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that.  Perhaps surprisingly, that doesn't work.  But   <link href="/public/error_stylesheets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> does work.  This actually makes sense because it seems like in a 404 or 500 condition, Rails has given up on the request to the HTTP server.

Comment: And what's happen when you links to `http://yourhost.com/error_stylesheets/styles.css`?

Comment: That works.  I should say I have this app as sub-site on domain.  So I have routes like http://domain/app/route  and app is symlinked public folder of a Rails app.